# How to rename the columns that are similar to current one plus one?

Tags: r, dataframe, logic

Could you help me with this problem: I have a dataset where columns are numeric values.
Some of the columns are sequencial. I would like to rename those sequencial column in the same name as from the column from where the sequence started.

Here a similar dataset to this example one:

```
fake_dataset <- data.frame(sample = paste0("sample_", sample(1:100, replace = T)),
                               "1678.47647" = runif(100, 1, 2),
                               "1679.84733" = runif(100, 1, 3),
                               "1680.87487" = runif(100, 2, 4),
                               "1800.35463" = runif(100, 1, 2),
                               "1811.47463" = runif(100, 2, 3),
                               "1823.52342" = runif(100, 2, 5)
                               )
    
    
colnames(fake_dataset) <- c("sample",
                                "1678.47647",
                                "1679.84733",
                                "1680.87487",
                                "1800.35463",
                                "1811.47463",
                                "1823.52342")
    
fake_dataset$sample <- NULL
```

My logic was to rename the column name value of the next sequencial column to the same name as the previous one, like this:

```
test <- function(data){
  new_names <- c()
  counter <- 0
  for (i in as.integer(colnames(fake_dataset))){
    counter <- counter + 1
    if(as.character( as.integer( names( data[counter] ) )) == as.character( as.integer( names( data[counter] ) )+1) ) {
      print("same!\n")
      colname( data[, counter]) <- colnames( data[, counter + 1])
    }else{
      print("different!\n")
    }
  }
}
```

But I haven't managed yet. Could anyone help?
Thank you for you time.

Comment: How does your expected output look like?

Comment: For example the column names would become sample 1678 1678 1678 1800 1811 1823

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may convert the `colnames` to `integer`, get the `diff`erence between adjacent elements to create a grouping variable, use that in `ave` to select the first element of the vector and assign it back as column names.

```
v1 <- as.integer(colnames(fake_dataset))
grp <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(v1) != 1))
new <- ave(v1, grp, FUN = function(x) x[1])

colnames(fake_dataset) <- new
```

-output

```
> colnames(fake_dataset)
[1] "1678" "1678" "1678" "1800" "1811" "1823"
```

NOTE: `data.frame/tibble/data.table` doesn't support duplicate column names.  It would be changed to unique values in subsequent transformations by using `make.unique` i.e. adding `.1`, `.2` for duplicates.  However, for a `matrix` the duplicate column names are allowed

Comment: But then also the column that are not sequential will change. I need to change the number of the contiguous sequences only. For example 1678 1678 1678 1800 1811 1823.

Comment: @flavinsky data.frame doesn't allow for duplicate coolumn names. You need to convert with `as.integer`

Comment: @flavinsky check the update

Comment: Thank you @akrun! It seems to work fine for now! Could you explain me the logic behind your code?

Comment: @flavinsky The second step, creation of `grp` is the key i.e whenever the difference between adjacent elements are  not equal to 1, the `cumsum` increments by 1.  This grp is used in `ave` to get the first element from v1